# 2018 MacBook Pro + Dell U2718Q, single cable for display and USB data

Tags: display, usb, hdmi, displayport

Can I connect a 2018 MacBook Pro to a Dell UltraSharp 27 4K Monitor (U2718Q) with a single cable that carries both the display data and the data for the USB ports of the display?

I tried a USB-C to DisplayPort cable, but none of the USB ports of the display would work until I also connected it to the MacBook Pro with a USB cable through one of it's USB upstream ports.

Note that I want to operate the display at full resolution (4K, 3840 x 2160) and a refresh rate of 60 Hz.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Technically speaking, you have a Thunderbolt 3 Type C port.  "C" is the physical charastic of the port, not the USB specification.  Being that it's Thunderbolt 3, its carrying several signals:

- PCIe
- USB 3.1
- DisplayPort
- Power

Your "end" device is a monitor that has several different inputs

- HDMI
- DispayPort (DP)
- Mini DisplayPort (mdP)
- USB

When you go from your MacBook's TB 3 port to the video in, you're not passing the USB signal; this is why you need a second cable for the USB functionality.  If this was a monitor that accepted Thunderbolt as an input, you could do this with one cable.

Comment: And can I use my USB-C (Thunderbolt 3) port on my MacBook Pro to pass the video signal to the monitor and at the same time charge my MacBook through thid Dell monitor?

Comment: @mistercake No, neither DisplayPort nor HDMI can provide power over that connection to charge your laptop. What you need is a dock. The U2718 is a fantastic monitor, I would find a dock/adapter solution over replacing it

Answer (score 0):

Dell UltraSharp 27 4K Monitor (U2718Q) DisplayPort

does not redistribute the input to its USB's.

[Dell](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/353145.pdf)